# Map layers do not render again past initial load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using [VueMapbox (0.4.1)](https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/) to utilize Mapbox GL in a Vue project.

```html
<template>
  <MglMap
    :accessToken="accessToken"
    :mapStyle.sync="mapStyle"
    :repaint="true"
    @load="onMapLoaded">
    <MglMarker
      :coordinates="someCoordinates"
      class="map-marker-wrapper">
      <div
        slot="marker"
        class="map-marker">
      </div>
    </MglMarker>
  </MglMap>
</template>

<script>
import Mapbox from 'mapbox-gl'
import { MglMap, MglMarker } from 'vue-mapbox'
import * as MAP from '@/constants/map'

// Vue-Mapbox documentation: https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/guide/basemap.html#adding-map-component

export default {
  name: 'Map',
  components: {
    MglMap,
    MglMarker
  },
  props: {
    someCoordinates: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    darkMode: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      accessToken: MAP.ACCESS_TOKEN,
      mapbox: null,
      map: null,
      actionsDispatcher: null
    }
  },
  computed: {
    mapStyle () {
      return this.darkMode ? MAP.COLOR_PROFILES.DARK : MAP.COLOR_PROFILES.LIGHT
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.mapbox = Mapbox
  },
  methods: {
    async onMapLoaded (event) {
      this.map = event.map
      this.actionsDispatcher = event.component.actions
    
      await this.actionsDispatcher.flyTo({
        center: this.someCoordinates
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

On the first load, everything works as expected:

[image: Correct Map]

But if I move to a different pseudo-route (say from `/#/Map` to `/#/Profile` and back), some of the map layers specified by my `mapStyle` (roads, city names,..) are not rendered anymore (default layers instead). The map also stops honoring any change of the `mapStyle` url, even when I specify `mapStyle.sync` in my template.

[image: Incorrect map]

If I hit the browser's reload button it loads the layers as expected as the entire app is reloaded from scratch, but I unfortunately cannot afford to do this by default.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, in the example of vue-mapbox, the variable map (this.map) is set by "event.map" which causes an error because the card is not refreshed afterwards.

In my case i just remove that (this.map = event.map) in my onMapLoaded function and this is great.

Have a good day.

Comment: quick addition if you have the same issue and still need to cache the map to use it later on: you can still do so. Declaring `map` outside of the `export` and further caching it like so `map = event.map` (instead of  `this.map = event.map` as the docs suggest) should do the trick, as it will prevent Vue from observing it.

Answer (score 0):

Despite I don’t know the syntax of Vue.js, the problem you are facing is that you are creating your layers in `map.on('load', ...` which is an event that happens only once, so when the style change happens, all the layers of the map style (including the ones created by custom code) are removed.
If you want to recreate your layers on style change, you have to do it in the event `map.on('style.load', ...`, but as said, I don’t see in your vue.js code where that is being done. If you share the part of the code where vue.js is invoking the methods it’ll be easier to help you

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Here VueMapbox already creates the map for me [every time the map is mounted on my screen](https://github.com/soal/vue-mapbox/blob/development/src/components/map/GlMap.js#L98)  so `load` is [fired every time I navigate to my map](https://github.com/soal/vue-mapbox/blob/e0edd17bde5fe8d1db7f44029e0e3399e2bf35ea/src/components/map/mixins/withPrivateMethods.js#L54). What I am doing here is grabbing the instance emitted by VueMapbox and caching its ref in my state so I can interact with it later on, this should not impact the behavior described above. (...)

Comment: (...) Specifying `.sync` on the `mapStyle` property should force the component to re-render (therefore reload the map entirely) when `mapStyle` changes in my state. This is detailed in their [documentation](https://soal.github.io/vue-mapbox/guide/basemap.html#map-loading) but it didnt work for me.

Comment: So then seems more like a VueMapbox bug. I work at low level with Mapbox and I can tell you that with `map.setStyle` all the layers are removed, including the custom ones, and they can only be created in `map.on('style.load', ...` if a style change is going to be used.